# Difference between "larder" and "pantry"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

What is the difference between *larder* and *pantry*? Is it size? Or content?

I found very similar definitions for both terms, something like

> a room/place in which food is stored.

Which of the words is better for a separate room next to the kitchen, and which is better for a food-dedicated cupboard? Or even for a separate house for food storage, like they used to have in castles?

Comment: Etymologically, and when the terms were used in mediaeval France, you kept *lard* (bacon) in a larder and *pain* (bread) in a pantry. So larders were more likely to be underground, because meat keeps better in a cooler place.

Comment: Today - very little difference. However I'm hoping someone can really explain the difference in, say, a medieval castle.

Comment: If you are seeking clarity in writing, the phrase "walk-in larder|pantry" may do the best job to indicate size and the fact that you are referring to a larger space. While many pantries may be built under stairs (especially in UK properties) so you can only walk in so far, I think people will understand the point.

Comment: @TheMathemagician [Here's](https://www.english-heritage.org.uk/content/imported-docs/u-z/warkworth-castle-pp.pdf) English Heritage's fine exploded diagram of Warkworth Castle. There are a 'buttery/pantry', lots of beer/wine cellars, and a 'food/fuel store' – but no 'larder'.

Comment: In current English, a _larder_ is where you keep your lard, while a _pantry_ is where you keep your pants. (Not.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That's because the builders build the beer/wine cellars first, and never moved on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that today there is no big difference. A long time ago meat was stored in vats of lard in cooler rooms (hence: larder), while  regular  foods  were kept in pantries. Today, pantry is used far more often than larder, especially in a residential context.[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pantry,%20larder,%20Pantry,%20Larder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,pantry;,c0;.t1;,larder;,c0;.t1;,Pantry;,c0;.t1;,Larder;,c0)

Comment: Vats of lard? Do you have a reference for this? Why would anybody do that?

Comment: That's something from my past readings,  let me look for it.

Comment: You can see this from the etymology; *larder* and *pantry* are both from mediaeval French; *lard* (bacon) was kept in *larders*, while *pain* (bread) was kept in pantries. You need to keep meat cool, while bread stores fine at room temperature.

Comment: Larder conjures up an old-fashioned house to me. It's probably due to my reading of a lot of Enid Blyton stories where 'raiding the larder' was exceedingly common.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's specifically a matter of usage.

"Pantry" is the [preferred term](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=larder%2Cpantry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clarder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpantry%3B%2Cc0) in the US for a separate room next to the kitchen or a closet/cupboard where food is stored, whereas "larder" and "pantry" are [more or less equally used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=larder%2Cpantry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clarder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpantry%3B%2Cc0) in the UK to refer to that place.

> [**pantry**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Pantry?s=t): a room or closet in which food, groceries, and other provisions, or silverware, dishes, etc., are kept.
>
> [**larder**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/larder): a room or place where food is stored; pantry.

Answer (score 0):

I think both can be either a cupboard or a separate room. These are the differences in my understanding.

pantry: a place for foodstuffs that last, such as flour, preserves, etc.

larder: a place where foodstuffs that don't last are kept, such as onions, eggs, milk, etc.

Comment: I always thought something along those lines, but with "larder" being a *more specific* term. Larders have to be cool, pantries can be too but don't have to. That would explain the near-interchangeability (these days, in the UK). Most food stores are kept cool, but lots of people (correctly but less precisely) call their larder a "pantry".

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to define the answer either then or now. Then back in mediaeval times it would be as previously described. In modern times it would be how it has followed down family usage. In my family we had a larder which was a room/cupboard backing onto the exterior wall where there was an air brick which kept the room cool and we stored cans,vegetables etc. and dripping.

Answer (score -1):

Surely Larder is for. The Anglo-Saxons, as much of their meat and perishable food was preserved and stored in fat, or lard.  The Pantry is Jorman French and comes
from the word for bread (pain) so either word is acceptable for food storage,
and are interchanged regularly in the UK still.